# NLP Getting the most common POS tag for a word and using it in the dictionary with Training Data

Tags: python, nlp, pos-tagger

I have a training text file with the following format (pos, word, tag):

1   i   PRP

2   'd  MD

3   like    VB

4   to  TO

5   go  VB

6   .   .

1   i   PRP

I am trying to build a dictionary so that when I input a new corpus with the following format (pos, word):

1   who

2   knows

3   what

4   will

5   happen

6   .

I will be able to tag these from the dictionary I've built with the training data.

the method I'm using is a counter in default dictionary to find the most common tag for a word. From my counter, I'm getting print results like this:

i   PRP 7905

'd  MD  1262

like    VB  2706

like    VBP 201

like    UH  95

like    IN  112

to  TO  4822

to  IN  922

So for the word "like", the tag with the highest counts is 'VB' at 2706. I want to my dictionary to take the tag with the highest count and attach it to my word so that if I put a test data set with just the (pos, word), it will return that tag. Here's my code so far:

```
file=open("/Users/Desktop/training.txt").read().split('\n')

from collections import Counter, defaultdict
word_tag_counts = defaultdict(Counter)
for row in file:         
    if not row.strip():
        continue          
    pos, word, tag = row.split()
    word_tag_counts[word.lower()][tag] += 1

stats = word_tag_counts
max(stats, key=stats.get)

with open('/Users/Desktop/training.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        column = line.split('\t') 
with open('/Users/Desktop/output.txt','w') as file: 
    for tag, num in d.items(): 
        file.write("\t".join([column[0], column[1], tag])+"\n")
```

I'm getting the error: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Counter' and 'Counter'

my output goal is in the same format as the original training file (pos pulled from original txt file, word from original txt file, tag from my dictionary):

Not sure what I can, i tried using lambda as well but it's not working. Anything will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you would like to achieve now is to have a `dict` mapping the lowercase form of each word to its most frequent POS tag. In `stats` you have how many times each POS tag of each word has appeared in the training data, stored in a `Counter`.

The line `max(stats, key=stats.get)` is where you're doing it wrong. `stats.get(word)` returns the `Counter` related to word `word`, and `Counter`s are not comparable in Python 3 (they are, however, in Python 2, but it doesn't really make sense). What's more is that, even if `Counter`s are comparable, the `max` function would just return the word with the maximum `Counter`, which is not what you want.

What we need to do is to use the `most_common()` method of `Counter`s. For each word `word`, `get()` its `Counter` (let's name it `c`) and call `c.most_common(1)[0][0]` to get its most frequent POS tag. The reason we need the subscripts `[0][0]` is that `most_common(k)` returns a list of top-`k` frequent items, and for each such item it returns a tuple containing the item itself, and its frequency. So the code would look like this:

```
pos_tags = {word: stats[word].most_common(1)[0][0] for word in stats}
```

And `pos_tags` is the mapping you desired. All you need to do is to finish the rest of your code (that applies this POS tagging method on other files).

Comment: awesome! i think this worked, the only issue i'm having now is printing onto another file. I'm going to create a new question on this, unless if you can think of a quick fix for what I've got.

Comment: @ChicJaab I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by printing. Do you want to save the mapping, or do you want to tag another file and save the results? If it's the former you might want to check out the `pickles` library.

Comment: my objective in the end is to create a dictionary in python where I can read a file with 2 columns (pos, word) and output a txt file with 3 columns (pos, word, tag). I think printing was the wrong way to say it, i'm trying to write the first two columns from the input file and add an additional column with the tags based on my dictionary. here's the link to my question. you've been great help, thanks!! [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52808884/write-results-onto-a-file-with-columns-from-the-input-data)